# Querying local cache first before querying server in Breeze JS

Tags: breeze

I have an app using Breeze to query the data. I want to first check the local cache and then the server cache if no results are returned (I followed John Papa's SPA jumpstart course). However, I have found a flaw in my logic which I am not sure how to fix. Assuming I have 10 items that match my query.

**Situation 1** (which works): I go to list page (Page A) displaying all 10. Hits server as cache is empty and adds all 10 to the cache. Then go to page displaying 1 result (Page B) which is found in the cache. So all good.

**Situation 2** (the problem): I go to the page displaying 1 record first (Page B). Then I go to my list page (Page A) which checks the cache and finds 1 record and because of this line (  `if (recordsInCache.length > 0)`) it exits and only shows that 1 record.

I somehow need to know that there are more records on the server (9) that are NOT in the cache, ie. the total records for this query is actually 10, I have 1 therefore I have to hit server for the other 9.

Here is my query for Page A:

```
function getDaresToUser(daresObservable, criteria, forceServerCall)
{
    var query = EntityQuery.from('Dares')
        .where('statusId', '!=', enums.dareStatus.Deleted)
        .where('toUserId', '==', criteria.userId)
        .expand("fromUser, toUser")
        .orderBy('deadlineDate, changedDate');

    return dataServiceHelper.executeQuery(query, daresObservable, false, forceServerCall);
}
```

and here is my query for Page B (single item)

```
function getDare(dareObservable, criteria, forceServerCall)
{
    var query = EntityQuery.from('Dares')
        .expand("fromUser, toUser")
        .where('dareId', '==', criteria.dareId);

    return dataServiceHelper.executeQuery(query, dareObservable, true, forceServerCall);
}



function executeQuery(query, itemsObservable, singleEntity, forceServerCall)
{
    //check local cache first
    if (!manager.metadataStore.isEmpty() && !forceServerCall)
    {
        var recordsInCache = executeLocalQuery(query, itemsObservable, singleEntity);
        if (recordsInCache.length > 0)
        {
            callCompleted();
            return Q.resolve();
        }
    }

return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);
```

}

```
function executeLocalQuery(query, itemsObservable, singleEntity)
{
    var recordsInCache = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
    if (recordsInCache.length > 0)
    {
        processQueryResults(recordsInCache, itemsObservable, singleEntity, true);
    }
    return recordsInCache;
}
```

Any advice appreciated...

Comment: If you want to just hit the server for comparison purposes then at some point (either when loading up your app or when you hit the list page) call inlineCount to compare total on server vs what you already have like shown in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390897/counts-in-breeze-js/16391856#16391856

Comment: Alternatively you may always fetch data for A before fetching the single entity for B getDaresForUser().then(getDare); (pseudo code).

Comment: Hmm - I was thinking about this - maybe ALL List pages should hit the server but all single entities should check the cache first?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just hit the server for comparison purposes then at some point (either when loading up your app or when you hit the list page) call inlineCount to compare total on server vs what you already have like shown in this answer stackoverflow.com/questions/16390897/counts-in-breeze-js/…

A way you can use this creatively while you are querying for the single record would be like this -

Set some variable in your view model or somewhere equal to total count

```
var totalCount = 0;
```

When you query the single record get the inline count -

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Dares')
    .expand("fromUser, toUser")
    .where('dareId', '==', criteria.dareId)
    .inlineCount(true);
```

and set `totalCount = data.inlineCount;` Same thing when you get the total items list, just set the totalCount to inlineCount then too so you always know if you have all of the entities.

Comment: Thanks PW Kad, however, the number of records will change depending on the query - e.g. I check for where not Deleted and where ToUser is set. I think I would need an Inline Count for each variant of the Query?

Comment: Yes, if you are querying the same data multiple ways then simply setting a flag probably isn't going to do what you want it to.  You could load up all of the data up front but that could definitely be taxing to the browser after time.  You could set up a key/value array for each query to see if they have been done yet / how many records for each count, that would work also.

Comment: Hmmm - that could work (ie. store if a query has been executed - however, if someone else added a new record then I would not be getting it from the server until the current user restarted - ie. you almost need a way of pinging the server per query to get a count back and have a way of invalidating the cache

Comment: Your needs are leaving breeze territory.  If you want to be notified of changes look at something like singalr

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been thinking about this problem more in the last year (and have since moved from Durandal + Breeze to Angular + Breeze :  In Angular you can cache the service call easily using

```
return $resource(xyz + params}, {'query': { method:'GET', cache: true, isArray:true }}).query(successArrayDataLoad, errorDataLoad);
```

I guess Angular caches the **params** of this query and knows when it has it already. So when I switch this method to use Breeze I lose this functionality and all my List calls are hit on every time.

So the real problem here is **List** data. Single Entities can always check the local cache and if nothing is returned then check the server (because you expect exactly 1).

However, List data varies by params. For example, if I have a GetGames call which takes in a CreatedByUserId, every time I supply a new CreatedByUserId I have to go back to the server.

So I think what I really need to do here to cache my List calls is to cache the Key for each call which is a combination of the QueryName and the Params.

For example, GetGames1 for UserID 1 and then GetGames2 for UserId 2.

The logic would be:  Check the Angular cache to see if this call has been made before in this session. If it has, then check the local cache first. If nothing is returned, check the server.

If it has not, check the server as the local cache MIGHT have some data in it for this query but it's not guaranteed to be the full set.

The only other way around it would be to hit the server each time first to get a count for that Query + Params and then hit the local cache and compare the count, but that is more inefficient.

Thoughts?